# How to make Pusher counting users?

Tags: laravel, pusher

I use this code to first join to the presence channel, secondly console.log numbers of users. I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined

```
var presenceChannel = Echo.join('presenceChat');
    presenceChannel.listen('EventEvent', (e) => {
       console.log(e);
   })
   .here((users) => {
       this.users = users;
       console.log(this.users);
       var count = presenceChannel.users.count;
       var me = presenceChannel.users.me;
       update_member_count(count);
       console.log(count);
       console.log(users)        
   })
```

I doubt I don't use Pusher the way I must.

I listen for EventEvent and dispatch $user when he logged in. What am I doing wrong? Or what should be series of steps I should take to count members of presence channel with Pusher? What confuses me is that in docs example there is no event listener. So how using Pusher?

Comment: it exactly means that `presenceChannel.users` is undefined

Comment: @Roman Bobrik I get the Object which contains data about user joined. I just don't get why the count isn't 1

Comment: Do `console.log(presenceChannel)` and see if there is `users`. Maybe you need to use `presenceChannel.members.count`? As in example: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels#members-count-number-

Comment: @Justinas Why would you give an answer? Thank you by the way. I console.log(presenceChannel) and changed users to members and it gave me an opportunity to continue my work. And I also think that I dont need Event Listener.

Answer (score 0):

*Copy from comment*

In [documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/presence-channels#members-count-number-) it's showing usage of `presenceChannel.members.count` and not `.users`.

You can always log your object to see it's properties using `console.log(presenceChannel)`